# How to get a Sequence of Values into Microsoft Access Form

Tags: ms-access

My question is probably easy but I can't find some examples of code to get the following results. I have a table with the name of wrecking services. I want to open form and display the company of the wrecking services. For Example, I have the following names for wreckers. Mario Wrecking service, TD Wrecking Service, and Beach Wrecking Service. When I open the form I want to display Mario Wrecking Service. When I open the form again I want to display TD wrecking service. and when I open the form again I want to display beach wrecking service. Lastly when I open the form again I want to go back to the beginning and I want to display Mario Wrecking Service again and so on. I just need some examples of codes something that could lead me to a possibility of accomplish this task.

Thanks for any suggestions that would be great.

Comment: What have you done to achieve the results you seek?  Also, can you explain why you would want to keep re-opening a form to get to the next company?  What happens when you have 100 companies?  You're going to keep opening that form until you get to the one you want?

Comment: I havent tried anything yet thats why I wanted some reference. well there is not hundreth companies only the ones I mention. Let me explain more. We have a database were we send wreckers when there is an accident but we dont want to send the same one for the same job we one wrecker a to go, and when I do another ticket or open another form I want wrecker b to go, then wrecker c. to give every company a chance to be fair but I don't want to remember what was the last one I send I want to give me such order that I know I gave every company a chance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the wrecker companies in a table.  tblWrecker.  This is where all the info about the company is kept.  Name, contact number, address, contact name, etc...  Put an AutoNumber field in the table.  Each wrecking company will be assigned an ID, which you will use to identify it.  This is considered a "normalized" database, and is the way it should be designed.

You can then run a quick query on your Accident table.  Select Top 1 WreckerID from AccidentTable ORDER BY AccidentID DESC.  This will give you the last wrecker used.  Then you would automatically assign WreckerID + 1.  Of course, you would have to make sure WreckerID + 1 existed in tblWrecker, and if not then you would go back to the beginning and assign WreckerID 1 to the task.

It's a decent amount of work, I'm not going to do your job for you, but I just outlined exactly how to do it.

Comment: Thanks Johny I just need a guide or a reference of someone has done something before like this.